# WP All Import - Convert unix timestamp to date when importing via a php function

Tags: unix-timestamp, wpallimport

I am doing a CSV import with a custom due date field.

I need to go from Unix Time format to d / m / Y format, I have found formula in the opposite format but not this one.

Can you help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Make an edit with a code sample that’s not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.